# Fetch distinct data from mongo array of objects data

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I need to get the distinct values from multiple mongodb array of objects data.

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5ae2dca33319b21f1289ad38"),
 "NumEntries": NumberLong(3),
 "Data": [
 {
   "Timestamp": "Apr 27 13:42 2018",
   "Client": "Manoj"
 },
 {
   "Timestamp": "Apr 27 13:42 2018",
   "Client": "Rajesh"
 },
 {
   "Timestamp": "Apr 27 13:43 2018",
   "Client": "Manoj"
 }
]
}
{
"_id": ObjectId("5ae2dc983319b26f4889ac8a"),
"NumEntries": NumberLong(1),
"Data": [
 {
   "Timestamp": "Apr 27 13:42 2018",
   "Client": "Vikas"
 } 
]
}
```

So, I need to find distinct Client Name from this like Manoj, Rajesh & Vikas
I am using Codeigniter MongoDB libarary. Tried so far:

```
$uniquemacids = $this->mongo_db->distinct('demologs', 'Data.Client');
```

It gives me boolean false / null as response

Comment: So you tried it and what happened? What is wrong?

Comment: @NeilLunn, It gives me boolean false / null as response

Comment: Query works as expected for me from the shell. Check your collection name and that you are pointing to the correct database on the connection

Comment: both connection & table is existing @NeilLunn, but i am getting null via codeigniter mongodb

Comment: its solved, in Codeigniter MongoDB library, remove "$this->wheres" from "distinct function"